# Smallest Distance-5 Quantum Error Correction Code?

Tags: quantum-information, quantum-computer, quantum-error-correction

Is it known/proven what the smallest quantum error correction code is that can correct arbitrary two-qubit Pauli errors? I can think of the nested/concatenated 5-qubit code or a 25-qubit version of the Shor (repetition) code, but I am not sure if there are codes requiring fewer qubits.

Comment: Crossposted to https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/q/12214/1011

Comment: I’m voting to close this question partly because it was crossposted.

Comment: @Qmechanic What is the policy in these cases: I though flagging is appropriate since those posts will be closed?  Or leave a comment & issue a custom close flag?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: Definitely link the crosspost in a comment, but don't flag unless it needs moderator attention. Vote to close if it should be closed.

Comment: @Qmechanic I thought the policy here was that immediate cross-posts are not allowed and thus should be closed?

Comment: @Norbert Schuch: I have a lot of sympathy for the position that immediate cross-posts should be avoided, but I think it is so far not written in stone that one cannot crosspost. Let me ping the other moderators for possible second opinions.

Comment: @Qmechanic Thanks. For some reason I had a policy along those lines in mind (maybe because of how previous flags got handled?).